# "Server start failed on port 9876: Error: EACCES: permission denied" on 'ng test' Angular Unit Tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, terminal, port, karma-runner

Whilst running my Unit Tests in watch mode, Chrome suddenly quit and I now can no longer run 'ng test'. This randomly occurred, and has not happened in over a year of working on these tests.

The **error** I am getting is:

```
Server start failed on port 9876: Error: EACCES: permission denied
```

I am running on a Mac, and have tried restarting both VSCode and my laptop multiple times. There is little to no documentation that I could find on the internet that describes my issue.

**My question:** *Why* am I getting this error and *how* do I fix it? Otherwise, how can I go about finding out more information about this issue by looking at the port usages and how I could go about resting them or similar.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need to uninstall node modules and reinstall them to fix the issue.
Please try to execute in super user mode(root user) like this

```
sudo rm -r node_modules
```

You may also need to re-install using:

```
sudo npm install
```

Use this command to run Unit Tests in watch mode

```
ng t --code-coverage --watch --browsers Chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by removing ./node_modules using:

`sudo rm -r node_modules`

and then re-installed using:

`npm install`